# My Dataset is showing a string when it should be a curly bracket set/dictionary

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, type-conversion

My dataset has a column where upon printing the dataframe each entry in the column is like so:
`{"Wireless Internet","Air conditioning",Kitchen}`

There are multiple things wrong with this that I would like to correct

- Upon printing this in the console, python is printing this:`'{"Wireless Internet","Air conditioning",Kitchen}'` Notice the quotations around the curly brackets, since python is printing a string.
- Ideally, I would like to find a way to convert this to a list like: `["Wireless Internet","Air conditioning","Kitchen"]` but I do not know how. Further, notice how some words so not have quotations, such as Kitchen. I do not know how to go about correcting this.

Thanks

Comment: it is not dictionry but `set()` - it also use `{}`. Dictionary would have keys and values. To convert `set()` to list use `list()`

Comment: Python may keeps all strings without quotations but it may add them when it print them only to inform that two words with space are one element.

Comment: maybe you should better change it when you read data, or write in file - it could be easier to create correct file then make corrections later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if it is string remove double quotes and curly braces from string, and use split by comma you will get the desired result

```
'{"Wireless Internet","Air conditioning",Kitchen}'.replace('{','').replace('}','').replace('"','').split(',')

#op
['Wireless Internet', 'Air conditioning', 'Kitchen']
```

Answer (score 0):

what you have is a set of words, curly brackets are for Dictionary use such as **{'Alex,'19',Marry','20'}** its linking it as a key and value which in my case it name and age, rather than that you can use **to_list** command in python maybe it suits your needs.